# jQuery selector cannot find an element that exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This doesn't work

```
var name= "#443.selected:first";
selectedEntity = $(name).attr('entityId');
```

This works

```
var name= "li.selected:first";
 selectedEntity = $(name).attr('entityId');
```

`selectedEntity` is undefined but an element does exist with id="443" class="selected".

Why doesn't the first example work?

Comment: Element IDs cannot begin with numbers...

Comment: @benM I cannot change the ID. what's a work around?

Comment: Well, IDs should be unique within the DOM, so specifying the class and `:first` should be superfluous. Can you confirm?

Comment: *"Element IDs cannot begin with numbers..."*  unless you are using HTML5

Comment: @benM not in this case. the IDs are not unique. even if they were I still have the problem that they begin with numbers as you said

Comment: I create a element with `id="123"` and `document.getElementById("123");` returns that element correctly.

Comment: Please, post your HTML peace of code.. make it easier to us..

Comment: On newer versions of jQuery (1.8.3+) it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/NsB66/

Comment: You need to be clearer about exactly what doesn't work...

Comment: @user521180 Your ID's **must** be unique. Fix that first.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense use `id`and `:first` together since `id` is suppose to be unique and browser returns only the first match

Comment: I think you need to fix the way you use `id` first.. See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandosavio/LGmxZ/2/) maybe it help someway

Comment: @fernandosavio unless the selector is passed to `document.querySelectorAll` or `document.querySelector`, in which case they will all be (wrongly)found just like in CSS. (which is what happens when you add `.selected` to it)

Comment: @BenM, actually [IDs ***can*** begin with numbers in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-id-attribute) the only restriction is that "The value must not contain any space characters."

Comment: Hehe, I was aware of that, but just generally assume that people are using HTML4 unless they explicitly say otherwise ;)

Comment: @BenM Your answer of using `[id="443"].selected:first` solved the problem but you seem to have deleted it. Could you answer it again so I can accept. thanks

Comment: I have undeleted the answer, glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector:

```
$('[id="443"].selected:first')
```

See this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGmxZ/)

Comment: So, I don't really understand what the problem is, since the OP reports that doesn't work... ;) +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

Though in HTML other than HTML5 IDs which start with a number are not allowed, your selector should work ([working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DG9W9/)). You must have an error elsewhere in your code and/or markup.

There are several issues you should address:

1. IDs must be unique otherwise your HTML is invalid
2. overqualifying the ID-Selector is bad for performance and due to 1) even not necessary
3. ID-Selectors only return the first element so using `:first` is useless (and also affected by point 1)
4. Don't use custom attributes like `entityId`. Instead use the [`data-` prefix](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). Then you can use [jQuerys data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to get/set those attributes. (Beware however that you cannot use [camelCase](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9066)).